# Deploying IOS App to customer using Enterprise Developers Account

Tags: ios, enterprise, account

I have an issue regarding distributing an IOS app to our customer using an Enterprise Developers Account. My client doesn't want to share their Enterprise account to me but then I have my own Enterprise Developers account. Can I use my own Enterprise Account to distribute apps to customer? Is there any alternative solutions?

Thanks and regards,
R e x

Comment: Short answer:No. You can't use your Enterprise License to distribute outside your company. This goes against the agreement you signed with Apple. One alternative may be the VPP.

Answer (score 0):

If possible and your client is willing, sit down with them or via Skype screen sharing and show them how to create the necessary certificates and distribution profiles in the provisioning portal. If they have the technical expertise they can do it themselves. Then you can build their app using their enterprise account.

Your client may just be skeptical about handing the account details to you.